A movie about a woman struggling with weight loss
I believe I found it on Youtube originally, but it was about a bigger woman who was pretty and ended up meeting a man that she liked and either lost the weight by surgery or by eating better (I really can't remember), but the movie showed her struggles and I am pretty sure there was a scene at a restaurant where they wanted to sit in certain seats, but they were fat-shamed. 
Other details:

I am pretty sure the main character had red hair as well. 
It came out in last decade.
It wasn't Shallow Hal and it was American and fictional.  
I feel as though it was more light-hearted, kind of like a Hallmark movie. (comedy and drama) 


Shallow Hal maybe

@cde The character in Shallow Hal never actually lost weight and she was a blonde, not a red head.

Hi. Was the film American? Was it a documentary or fictional? What was the genre?

It wasn't Shallow Hal and it was American and fictional

And do you remember if it was a comedy (Date Movie fits most of these details, for instance) or played seriously?

I feel as though it was more light-hearted, kind of like a Hallmark movie. (comedy and drama)

This is possibly the Lifetime movie Lying to Be Perfect from 2010.

An overweight magazine editor leads a double life as a sassy advice columnist at night. To keep her alter ego a secret she agrees to lose weight with two of her friends and embarks on a life changing journey. 

The protagonist is a redhead and there's a dispute about seats in a restaurant at some point involving weight discrimination. She also meets a man she likes, which complicates matters. It was based on the novel The Cinderella Pact by Sarah Strohmeyer. Here's the trailer: 




This is it! Thank you so much, i have been trying to find it for a very long time!
